# MKCoordinateSpanMake error Xcode 11, iOS 13.2

Tags: swift

Getting compile time error while using MKCoordinateSpanMake
'MKCoordinateSpanMake' is unavailable in Swift

1. 'MKCoordinateSpanMake' has been explicitly marked unavailable here (MapKit.MKCoordinateSpanMake)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call MKCoordinateSpan `init(latitudeDelta: CLLocationDegrees, longitudeDelta: CLLocationDegrees)` instead.

Answer (score 10):

`MKCoordinateRegionMake` was renamed to `MKCoordinateRegion`

`MKCoordinateSpanMake` was renamed to `MKCoordinateSpan`